# If I store data using Xamarin.Essentials Preferences, then how can I retrieve that data in an Android Splash activity?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

If using Xamarin.Essentials Preferences class to store application preferences in a key/value store.

`Preferences.Set("my_key", "my_value");`

Then how can I get this back in the `SplashActivity` of the application?

Please NOTE, there's a similar question / answer on SO that's now over 9 years old with an answer pointing to links that no longer exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Android, *Xamarin.Essentials: Preferences* uses the native "SharedPreferences", so to retrieve a string back from SharedPreferences a string stored via Essentials, this would work:

```
var sharedName = $"{AppInfo.PackageName}.xamarinessentials.versiontracking";
var sharedPreferences = Application.Context.GetSharedPreferences(sharedName, FileCreationMode.Private);
var value = sharedPreferences.GetString(yourKey, null);
```

You can review the Essentials' Android implementation at the following link to see Xamarin's code:

re: https://github.com/xamarin/Essentials/blob/develop/Xamarin.Essentials/Preferences/Preferences.android.cs

**Note**: I do not believe anything in Xamarin.Essentials Preferences or VersionTracking uses an initialized Forms application at all, so you can "just" reference the **Essentials's Preferences API** directly in your SplashActivity instead of directly using the native calls.

Answer (score 2):

Let's start by saying that the Android Splash screens are regular Android Activities.

Also, `Xamarin.Essentials` package is installed as part of the Xamarin.Android project which allows you to use it as you would in the Shared project.

Having said the above you can retrieve your preference values from the Android project with `Xamarin.Essentials` using something like:

```
bool isNewClient = Xamarin.Essentials.Preferences.Get("Key", defaultValue: true);
```

Hope this helps.-